# How to read a file from MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

Read content of the file in mongo using java

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/address.txt");

GridFS gridfs = new GridFS(db, "sample");
GridFSInputFile gfsFile = gridfs.createFile(file);
gfsFile.setFilename("address");
gfsFile.save();

BasicDBObject info = new BasicDBObject();
  info.put("name", "MongoDB");
  info.put("fileName", "address");
  info.put("rawName", "address.txt");
  info.put("rawPath", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/");

coll.insert(info, WriteConcern.SAFE);
GridFS gridfs = new GridFS(db, "sample");
GridFSDBFile file = gridfs.findOne("address");
System.out.println(file);
```

on priting a file I need the content of the file to be printed.
How can we do that in java ??
Is that we suppose to use inputstream ? or is there any other way to achieve it ?

Comment: why are you adding file information in the different collection? You simply save it as metadata with GridFSInputFile.

Comment: @dev yep sure I got it (Y)

Comment: Please refer to this page.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34766254/how-to-get-file-from-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

You can use the InputStream provided the getInputStream() method of GridFSDBFile

refer to [GridFSDBFile API Docs](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/gridfs/GridFSDBFile.html)